# active_admin error when adding new resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I want to build a user management app using Rails, 
At first, I created user model with controller, some feature for user: login, sign up, active email, password reset manually( I didn't use gem 'devise' ).
I used this book: Rails Tutorials Book.
After that, I installed gem 'active_admin' to generate admin panel to manage user.
I did add User to active_admin: resource User but I receive an error.

Some picture about this error.

My error:
[image]

Another Model such as Admin User and Comment is still working.

Can you help me?

Update my: User model

[Link to my code](http://pastebin.com/BU7QyRed)

Sorry for this inconvenience.

Comment: If you wont paste some code it will be hard to help you, paste the User model and AA view file

Comment: i had updated my code. thanks

Comment: can you paste Users.rb the activeadmin file?